# How to test method of JavaFX controller?

Tags: java, unit-testing, javafx-8

I was trying to use TestFX to test my application. I would like to run the test for the method of my controller.

Main.java:

```java
public class Main extends Application {
    try{
        new Flow(ManageCtrl.class).startInStage(primaryStage);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

ManageCtrl.java:

```java
@ViewController("/FPManage.fxml")
public class ManageCtrl extends AnchorPane {

    @FXML // fx:id="email"
    private TextField email; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    public void setEmail(String address) {
        this.email.setText(address);
    }
}
```

ManageCtrlTest.java:

```java
public class ManageCtrlTest extends ApplicationTest {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try {
            new Flow(ManageCtrl.class).startInStage(stage);
        } catch (FlowException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ManageCtrlTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetEmail() {
        ManageCtrl instance = new ManageCtrl();
        instance.setEmail("test@gmai.com");

        assertEquals("test@gmail.com", ((TextField)GuiTest.find("#email")).getText());
    }
}
```

But I get the following Exception:

```java
testSetEmail Failed: java.lang.illegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Test worker
java.lang.illegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Test Worker
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've never used TestFX, so there might be a specific solution for that framework.  Andy Till created a [JUnit rule for testing on the JavaFX application thread](https://gist.github.com/andytill/3835914).  Perhaps you could adapt that for your purpose, though I would expect a framework named TestFX to handle such things natively.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask in 2 different place.  But I got the answer from the author: [#207](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX/issues/207). The point is to use DataFX API: `Flow flow = new Flow(ManageCtrl.class);
        FlowHandler handler = flow.createHandler();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(handler.start()));
        stage.show();
        FlowView view = handler.getCurrentView();
        controller = (ManageCtrl) view.getViewContext().getController();`  With That controller, we can call method inside.

Comment: 5 min is too short for me to preview the result. >.<    <!-- language: lang-js -->`Flow flow = new Flow(ManageCtrl.class);`  Still failed to add a line break, but the help says add 2 space will add    <br />. Also failed to add high light syntax.

Comment: you can [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and mark it as correct.  I suggest you do that by summarizing the offsite information (so the answer is self-contained on stack overflow).  That is better than posting code into the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IllegalStateException` is related to the **nature of JavaFX and TestFX**.

`ManageCtrl` extends from `AnchorPane` which is one of JavaFX's `Scene` objects that all need to be constructed within the JavaFX thread (also known as JavaFX application thread or JavaFX user thread). You can use `ApplicationTest#interact` to construct `ManageCtrl` within the JavaFX thread:

```
interact(() -> {
    ManageCtrl controller = new ManageCtrl();
    controller.setEmail("test@gmail.com");
});
```

However this will throw a `NullPointerException` which is caused by the **nature of DataFX** which is used with `new Flow(ManageCtrl.class)`.

`new Flow(ManageCtrl.class).startInStage(stage)` will inject all `@FXML`-annotated fields in the controller with objects defined in your `@ViewController`—`new ManageCtrl()` won't. We can solve this problem by constructing `ManageCtrl` into the field `controller` before the test:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Flow flow = new Flow(ManageCtrl.class);

    // create a handler to initialize a view and a sceneRoot.
    FlowHandler handler = flow.createHandler();
    StackPane sceneRoot = handler.start();

    // retrieve the injected controller from the view.
    FlowView view = handler.getCurrentView();
    controller = (ManageCtrl) view.getViewContext().getController();

    // attach the sceneRoot to stage.
    stage.setScene(new Scene(sceneRoot));
    stage.show();
}
```

You can now test your controller with:

```
@Test
public void should_set_email() throws Exception {
    // when:
    interact(() -> {
        controller.setEmail("test@gmail.com");
    });

    // then:
    verifyThat("#email", hasText("test@gmail.com"));
}
```

---

The whole thing is detailed in an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX/issues/207). I've also created a [pull request on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/datafx/datafx/pull-request/31/) that tries to simplify testing on this regard.