# I am trying to write test cases for JavaFX, how to get started?

Tags: javafx

This is my code I am unable to write Junit test cases. I am new to writing the test cases 1st time I am writing the test cases in Javafx and I am also do not how to start writing the test cases in Javafx. I am using javafx8 and I am using this jar file.

junit 4.12
hamcrest 1.3
mockito-all-1.9.5
testfx-core-4.0.14-alpha
TestNG 6.8.1-testing-6.8.1-dist.jar

```
public class SampleController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private Button applyButton;
    @FXML
    private TextField firstName;
    @FXML
    private TextField lastName;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        applyButton.disableProperty().bind(
                firstName.textProperty().isEmpty()
                        .or(
                                lastName.textProperty().isEmpty()
                        ));
    }

    @FXML
    private void applyButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) {

        label.setText(firstName.getText());
    }

}


// this my respective test class

public class SampleControllerNGTest {

    public SampleControllerNGTest() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUpMethod() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDownMethod() throws Exception {
    }

    /**
     * Test of initialize method, of class SampleController.
     */
    @Test
    public void testInitialize() {
        System.out.println("initialize");
        URL url = null;
        ResourceBundle rb = null;
        SampleController instance = new SampleController();
        instance.initialize(url, rb);
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
    fail("The test case is a prototype.");

    }

}
```

Comment: what do you want to test?

Comment: i want to test that textFields values from my value which i am passing when i click button

Comment: Do you want unit test without screen or integration test with full environment?

Comment: Maybe a part of the answer :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41732654/how-to-test-javafx-mvc-controller-logic

Comment: Check this sample code from my project: https://github.com/Arxa/video_text_detection/blob/master/src/test/java/MainTest.java